# Automount image file as UnionFS overlay

Tags: linux

I wish to auto-mount an image file at system start-up using UnionFS and overlay settings files (e.g. /etc/network/interfaces) on top of the stock /etc directory files allowing for user customisation.

I'm using an embedded Linux distro (Kernel 3.14.28, just in case you were wondering) and can manually achieve the desired result after the system reaches the login prompt.

I now wish to automate the process during system start-up.

My thinking was that /etc/fstab would provide all the functionality required to achieve this. However, I'm experiencing difficulty with auto-mounting the FAT partition and subsequent UnionFS mount during system boot.

My /etc/fstab can be seen below:

```
# start: /etc/fstab file
/dev/root   /               auto       defaults              1  1
proc        /proc           proc       defaults              0  0
devpts      /dev/pts        devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0  0
usbdevfs    /proc/bus/usb   usbdevfs   noauto                0  0
tmpfs       /run            tmpfs      mode=0755,nodev,nosuid,strictatime 0  0
tmpfs       /var/volatile   tmpfs      defaults              0  0

# mount the user data image and then mount the unionfs user setting overlays
/dev/mmcblk2p1/userdata.img      /userdata       vfat    loop,auto,rw,exec                               0       0
/userdata/etc               /etc            unionfs    dirs=/userdata/etc=rw:/etc=ro,auto   0       0
# end: /etc/fstab file
```

During boot I see:

```
...
EXT3-fs (mmcblk2p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) readonly on device 179:11.
devtmpfs: mounted
Freeing unused kernel memory: 352K (80e3b000 - 80e93000)
INIT: version 2.88 booting
unionfs: error accessing lower directory '/userdata/etc' (error -2)
unionfs: read_super: error while parsing options (err = -2)
Starting udev
udevd[187]: starting version 182
EXT3-fs (mmcblk2p5): using internal journal
EXT3-fs (mmcblk2p5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
FAT-fs (mmcblk1p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
EXT3-fs (mmcblk1p2): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT3-fs (mmcblk1p2): using internal journal
EXT3-fs (mmcblk1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
FAT-fs (mmcblk2p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
EXT3-fs (mmcblk2p2): using internal journal
EXT3-fs (mmcblk2p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
EXT3-fs (mmcblk2p3): using internal journal
...
```

It appears that the system is trying to perform the UnionFS mount before the mount-point (/userdata) is ready. My understanding was that partitions listed in /etc/fstab are mounted sequentially. If this is not the case please educate me;)

So, my question is : **How can I change the /etc/fstab (and any other files) to get the auto-mount effect that I want?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

*Code examples is in the end of this post*. Nowdays systemd reads fstab and then try to mount the fs in parallel. The systemd default mount-scripts are created at boot-time and you find them in

```
'run/systemd/generator'
```

You can either try to use the noauto parameter in fstab which mounts the fs only when its accessed. Which may  have sideffcts so that you in some cases have to try to access the mountpoint two times before it being activated.

Maybe one can circumstance that with giving the program that access the mountpoint a delay. Really - I don't know if thats true. However, the other solution is to make a systemd startup script where you override the reading of fstab. That can be done in two ways, either by tell systemd to read a rc.local file in which you specify the mount option, or the (I suppose) more correct way - write scripts for systemd only.

I give examples both are from my own mount-scripts which I found out from other examples.

I will later edit this post to add links from where I fond the resources I used that helped me create those scripts. Both examples needs two files. DISCLAIMER I don't claim that the mountpoits is the correct following the standards. For example, I mount a folder in the root-directory. It is just my own attempts while I am still inexperienced in linux and do my own stuff in my own way on my own testbench-system. It is a work in progress and for now, quite sloopy done. Use the examples as reference only and try to be more strict on the standards than I am. Also, i suppose one could improve those files in many ways. Comments and suggestions are highly appreciated.

1.use the rc-local

```
#This file should be named /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/usr/local/sbin/rc.local

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/rc.local
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes
SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

.

```
#Local multi-user startup script.
#this file should be named as  /usr/local/sbin/rc.local and have the executable attribute set.
#!/bin/sh
mount -L BIGDATA /BIGDATA
#2do, If LABEL not found, Add failback  to  search for UUID 
LBL=$(blkid -s LABEL  $(mount | grep " / ") | cut -d "=" -f 2-2 | tr -d '"')

mount -t aufs -o dirs=/BIGDATA/mountslinks/dist-global_rw/newfiles_rw/home=rw:/BIGDATA/mountslinks/dist-global_rw/global_rw/home=rw:/BIGDATA/mountslinks/dist-local_rw/"$LBL"/home=rw none /home
mount -t aufs -o dirs=/BIGDATA/mountslinks/dist-global_rw/newfiles_rw/root=rw:/BIGDATA/mountslinks/dist-global_rw/global_rw/root=rw:/BIGDATA/mountslinks/dist-local_rw/"$LBL"/root=rw none /root
```

2.*Use systemd only* (I switched to this one after a few reboots. Not because the first one didn't work - in fact, it works well (on my system) - more because I firstly wanted to learn this approach as well, and also I think this is more future-proof.

```
#this one is an edited version of the one Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
Before=local-fs.target
[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-label/BIGDATA
Where=/BIGDATA
Type=ext4
Options=defaults,nofail

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

.

```
[Unit]
Before=local-fs.target
Requires = BIGDATA.mount
After = BIGDATA.mount

[Mount]
What=noauto,x-systemd.requires=/BIGDATA,x-systemd.automount
Where=/home/peter
Type=aufs
Options=br=/BIGDATA/mountslinks/lubuntu/new_rw/home/peter=rw:/BIGDATA/mountslinks/lubuntu/local_rw/home/peter=rw:/BIGDATA/mountslinks/lubuntu/shared_rw/home/peter=rw


[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Also, I suppose one in fstab could add parameter within fstab telling systemd the mount order.